# How to make tail wait for files to be created before tailing them

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tail

I've been trying to find a way to make `tail` wait for files to be created and then start tailing them.

For example, let's assume I have a `logs` directory which hasn't been created yet, but my application will create it. Let's say I have another process in which I'd like to run `tail -F logs/*.log` and have it start tailing all the files as soon as they are created. How would I go about doing that?

And another thing: if `tail` is tailing some file which is deleted, is it possible to have it start tailing it again, if it's re-created?

Comment: Duplicate on Unix.SE: [monitor files (ala tail -f) in an entire directory (even new ones)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39729/monitor-files-ala-tail-f-in-an-entire-directory-even-new-ones)

Comment: Thanks! I had a look and installed it. I tried the example in the link you provided, but I can't seem to get it to work. Would you mind providing some more explanations and an example?

Comment: So what happened with that example?

Comment: I'm just getting an empty console.

Comment: Yes, seems `multitail` doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some roughness, this works:

```
while inotifywait -q .; do kill $PID; tail -F -n 0 * & PID=$!; done
```

Once anything in a directory changes, the `tail` command gets restarted.

Answer (score 1):

> And another thing: if tail is tailing some file which is deleted, is it possible to have it start tailing it again, if it's re-created?

While you are `tail`ing some file which is truncated and re-created; `tail` command handles it automatically. You don't need to re-issue the `tail` command for that particular file.

Comment: This is only true as long as the directory has not been deleted. Once it's deleted, `tail` reports it and stops looking for changes there. If your application re-creates the folder, `tail` will continue rolling data.